# How to get variable in FlowScope?

Tags: spring-webflow

In my Spring web flow, I have a variable in `FlowScope` named "action", and I want to check this variable in validation method;

```
\\\\\\
    if(action=="copy"){
    doCopy;
    }else{
    doOther;
    } 
\\\\\\\
```

But I don't know how to call "action" variable. Please help me.

Answer (score 5):

Can't you access it like this:

```
RequestContext rc = RequestContextHolder.getRequestContext();
String action = (String) rc.getFlowScope().get("action");
```

Or, without the typecast if you know the type:

```
String action = rc.getFlowScope().getString("action");
```